# uwsgi with python3 how to get the plugin(not from apt)

Tags: plugins, python3

how to run uwsgi with python 3 instead of python 2? I've  compiled the latest version of uwsgi, and i know there are plugins which can be installed by apt-get , but how  can I get it(shall i compile it from source?)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps provided here

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Install.html

**EDIT:**

Or

```
1. sudo apt-get install python3-dev
2. sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
3. which easy_install
4. sudo python3 <Output of which command> pip
5. sudo pip install uwsgi
```

Comment: is plugins/python support python3? I find out somewhere there's a plugin called python3.(written in a uwsgi ini file as plugins=python3)

Comment: Updated my answer with alternate method. Please check that.